# Loading page generates exception 'Timed out waiting for page load'

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, c#

I'm navigating to a webpage using Firefox driver. The page is loaded correctly but I'm getting this exception and the test crashes

```
Timed out waiting for page load
```

I've tried to add some `Thread.Sleep();` and explicit waits but still getting the same error.

Is there a work-around to get rid of this problem??

Comment: put an explict timeout and load the page, i guess page is not getting completely loaded within implicit time driver.get() command which it is used.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use WaitForReadyState?

Here is my example:

```java
 /// <summary>
        /// Waits the state of for ready within 30 sec.
        /// </summary>
        public void WaitForReadyState()
        {
            var state = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var wait = new WrapperSeleniumWait(this, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                wait.Until(wrapper =>
                {
                    state = JSExecutor.ExecuteScript(@"return document.readyState").ToString();
                    return state.Equals("complete", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                }
                    );
            }
            catch (WebDriverException)
            {
                if (WindowHandles.Count != 1) return;
                SwitchToWindow(WindowHandles[0]);
                state = JSExecutor.ExecuteScript(@"return document.readyState").ToString();
                if (!(state.Equals("complete", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))) throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: nope I didn't try that, I'll try it and I'll keep you posted with the result. thanks :)

Comment: Infact, I'm still getting the same error,but I just wanted to add that this error occurs in the Click() method on a WebElement object

Comment: Hmm, it's another question. Try to click in a such way:http://pastebin.com/bwYrPGtC

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a WebDriverWait  along with one of the methods in the ExpectedConditions class.   Basically, just wait for a element on the page using a pre-defined expected condition.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar kind of problem earlier. Here is my suggestions
1- Don't just wait for page to load write a logic for it.Try to make several attempts after a given interval. (refer below mention code. language is perl)
e.g.

```
my $wait =some_value;
my $url ="something";
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
eval{
$selenium->get($url);
}

if($@){
print "$i attempt became unsuccessful.";
sleep($wait);
}

else{
print "Got the url in $i attempt";
last;
}
}

if($i>5){
print "All attempts failed.";
}
```

2- Some times its not a selenium problem. Since selenium starts a news instance of firefox , it check for the certificate which is going to be loaded. If you have demo certificate try to add it to firefiox manually.

3- Check your firewall settings. Some routers block automated queries. e.g. If you are using belkin router they have an explicit firewall build in the router. Disable it.